# When does the amount transfered to merchant's paypal account after capturing the partial amount?

Tags: paypal, authorization, capture

I have been searching for this question but couldn't find anything clear. I have a woocommerce website with "Paypal Express" integrated as payment gateway. I have already set the payment action as "Authorization".

The scenario is:

If a customer books a rental item from a site and make the payment. The total amount is for example $1000, which includes Security Deposit (Refundable) of $250.

My questions are:
1. The main amount i-e; $750, will it be transferred immediately to merchant's paypal account??
2. Will the security deposit(for e.g. $250) get held reserved just right after capturing the main amount??

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main amount i-e; $750, will it be transferred immediately to merchant's paypal account??

Answer : If you run DoCapture on 750, the amount will be capture and move to the merchant account, If you DoCapture 1000, all of the money will be transfer to merchant account.

2. Will the security deposit(for e.g. $250) get held reserved just
   right after capturing the main amount??

Answer : It will be keep in Authorization. If you do not capture, after 30 days it will be expired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot.